# Prevent page flicker on load caused by javascript content injection

Tags: javascript

I use javascript to inject content into my page when it's loaded. It's working fine except it flickers just a little bit when it loads. Does anyone have an idea how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you be more detailed about what you mean by flickering? Are you talking about when you first visit the page? Or is it after awhile and the js in injected?

Comment: Like the first 0.1s of loading the page as the js injects the html div by div.

Comment: Do you have CSS in the injected html? You might need to load that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try show the DOM only when it is ready, and use a loading message or spinner...

Comment: What's the cleanest way to do? css style on body ?

Comment: you can define a class for when to put it to the DOM while it is loading (for example: .loading) and define the css rules for that class, where you hide it or do whatever you want to define. Then add or remove this class to element using javascript